# Can anyone identify this compass mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I've been trying to find out what mod adds the coordinate/compass display shown in the red square on the following image:

[image: Mod screenshot]

I've searched through my default download locations and web history, but none of the items found give this feature!

If anyone can identify it I would be most grateful as I've been looking for days to no avail.

Comment: It turn's out that it is part of Zombe mod's "compass mod". Its either not documented very well or I'm blind :)

Comment: Make this an answer so I can upvote you for rep!

Comment: Also, what is that map in the other corner?

Comment: Dan, the map is Rei's minimap with the Round border selected in it's configuration menu. -  http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482147-100b181b19pre5dec12-reis-minimap-v29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probaly the Ingame Info Mod by DaftPVF, which allows you to add lots of info to the screen.

It can be downloaded from [the thread on the minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/124117-100-daftpvfs-mods/#ingame_info)

Comment: I know that I don't have that installed, but it looks like it can do what I want, and a lot more which is good :) Thanks